# Generic detection of subimages in images with openCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

Disclaimer: I'm a computer vision rookie.

I have seen a lot of stack overflow posts of how to find a specific sub-image in a larger image.

My usecase is a bit different since I don't want it to be specific and I'm not sure how I can do this (if it's even possible, but I have a feeling it should).

I have a large datasets of images, of sometimes, some of this images are a combination of two or more other images of the dataset. I'd like to automatically crop theses "combinations" to isolate the sub-images.

So the tasks would be to process each image of the dataset, and check if there are abnormal boundaries that could mean the image is a combination.

Example using great stock images:

[image: combination of two images]

What I've tried:

I've seen that houghs transform could be used for line detection in images but I'm couldn't achieve anything using this.

Comment: hough is completely useless here. and so is all the other "youtube tutorial" level stuff. -- sobel or other derivative, row/column sums, analyze peaks, cut.

Comment: There is no way of knowing if a long, straight line is caused by two images being pasted together, or by something in the image itself, unless you understand the contents and context of the images. Doing this properly would require a complex AI. No simple processing will solve it. But if you know there are two images pasted horizontally, you can of course find the most likely joint using simple logic like @Christoph’s answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `cv.Sobel` or other derivative kernel (with `cv.filter2D`) to find edges
- Sum along pixel columns to score each for "edginess". `np.sum` or `np.mean` do that.
- Some thresholding and `np.argsort` and indexing to find best candidates.
- cut (take slices out of array)

edge map:

[image: edge map]

edgy plot:

[image: edgy plot]

slices to take:

```
array([[   0,  578],
       [ 578, 1135],
       [1135, 1136]], dtype=int64)
```

Pictures:

[image: pic 1] [image: pic 2]

complete notebook: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/e1ba1ce7a6fba446288275d91f66261c

Comment: This is a good solution (+1!) if you know there are exactly two images pasted horizontally. It does not help in the case where you don’t know if images are pasted together, how many there are, or how they are pasted together. Which I think cannot be solved without a huge expense.

Comment: true. if the number of pictures is in question, a human should determine an absolute threshold (0.2 seems good here) and have it cut based on that, instead of relative to peak response as I've done here. -- I can imagine other schemes that don't just sum the edge responses but threshold and count positives. -- if the pasting is grid-like at all, this should work. if it's a "tree map" where one cut can always be made, recursively, then that too. I've made assumptions based on the example picture. to handle padding would need work. generalization is warranted after differing data is presented.

Comment: Considering he is taking peak values, from what I understand it does not matter how much subimages are in the image, I can just split on these values. I'm gonna try but this seem great ! (Although @CrisLuengo I agree there will be cases where this will not work, it still solves a lot of cases !) Thank you both

Comment: it's also conceivable to use more than a 2x2 neighborhood for edge detection, or to select and ignore (longer) edges that aren't perfectly vertical. or to involve any kind of texture analysis or analysis of histograms, to tell pictures apart. -- it's true that this can't be solved in general. counterexamples can always be constructed. AI is often the most promising approach... but also take work.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yeah I was more thinking of making differents attemps for each image to split vertically or horizontally using your code, it's not as efficient as AI but probably easier to perform (even if it can take time, I don't need it to be particularly fast).

I still have a question though, I'm trying your code, and all I get after the filter2D step is just a full black image.

Comment: my `imshow` there is a custom thing for jupyter notebooks but it reacts mostly like `cv.imshow` (floats scaled 0.0 .. 1.0). inspect the min() and max() of the array you are trying to show. if you use `imwrite`, even floats need to be scaled 0 .. 255. -- the filter2D is fairly cheap, and so is all the following stuff. this should be significantly cheaper than a neural network.

Comment: The imshow was working fine with the example image you used in your notebook, i'm right now trying to use a real image from my dataset.

Update: I had a thin white border on the left of my image and it appeared to mess everything up, juste cropped it and it's working !